# Cannot open backup device '\\Servername\backup$\Database\databasename.bak'. Operating system error 53(The network path was not found.)

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, sql-execution-plan

I used

> Microsoft SQL Server 2012 (SP3) (KB3072779) - 11.0.6020.0 (X64) 
>   Standard Edition (64-bit) on Windows NT 6.1  (Build 7601: Service Pack 1)
>
> 1)I have an Maintenance Plan, which backup sql database in a network share.
>
> 2) Backup execute every day in 17:00
>
> 3) Sql server services and SQL Agent services running domain accounts
>    Domain\SQLServer
>
> 4) Remote Network share : \\Servername\backup$\Database\databasename.bak
>
> 5) Network path "backup$" have a full rights domain accounts
>    Domain\SQLServer and path "Database" have a full rights domain accounts
>    Domain\SQLServer.
>
> 6) But i get this error 
>   **Cannot open backup device '\\Servername\backup$\Database\databasename.bak'. Operating system error 53(The network path was not found.).**
>
> 7) I can't understand what could be the problem.
>
> 8) I noticed one interesting moment. When i forced update sql server in a sql management studio and run manually maintenance plan, backup run success and databasename.bak appears on remote network share, but when i start maintenance plan automatically, plan success work 2-3 days but then history again **Cannot open backup device '\\Servername\backup$\Database\databasename.bak'. Operating system error 53(The network path was not found.)**. I have no idea what it could be.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hey guys I have solved this problem.

The problem was in Kaspersky Endpoint Security 10. I have stopped module "protection from network attacks" and backup have success to remote network share and "lanman service" working normal. Thanks for the wireshark. Somehow module "protection from network attacks" blocked correct working lanman service and blocked 445 port which use lanman service.

Comment: Well, then either post a good answer that tells us what the problem was and how you solved it, leave it open in the hopes that someone else does that (post a good answer), or delete it if you no longer need it.